# Conceptual question on current vs current density Ohm's law

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, dimensional-analysis

The current density $j = \sigma E$ has units number/(seconds * area). Sigma is the conductance $\sigma = 1/R$, $R$ is the resistance. $E$ is the electric field.

We want to make the analogy to $i$, the regular current. Multiply dimensionally by the area $A$.
$i = j A = \sigma (E A)$. This gives $V=EA$, which of course has the wrong units compared to the desired $V=E d$...

Can someone explain why the units dont match up? I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Aren't the units for current density $\mathrm{A/m^2} = \mathrm{C/s/m^2}$?

Comment: yes? that is like my only assumption lol

Comment: The units of $\sigma$ are $\mathrm{S/m}$ where $\mathrm{S}$ is the unit of conductance, [siemens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_(unit)). What unit is "number" in the first sentence?

Comment: Why do you think that resistance and resistivity are the same?

Comment: I dont... anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_density#Calculation_of_current_densities_in_matter). $\sigma$ is the conductivity (not conductance), and its inverse is resistivity (not resistance). Resistivity has units of $\Omega\,$m so that's where the extra dimension of length is coming from from in your $V=EA$.